# How fix error "failure in EnsureDBVersion()"

Tags: go, goose

I have project with **Go** . I use **goose** to bind migration with data . After install , i create file .sql and test it . But it not working . 
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Don't paste images of text. They are very hard to read. And for the visually impaired, they are impossible to read, and they can't be indexed or search. Instead, just copy-and-paste the text directly into your question.

Comment: And please submit relevant code snippets related to the error.